# $_SESSION[id] undifined error with people with no session how remove it?

Tags: php, session

Basically this everything I have been trying to have session variable on same page where people that have sessions and people that don't have session. When you don't have a session I get an undefined variable error. Its like any normal session example.

```
$session = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Any ideas how I can remove this error so when people without a session will not see this and the people with a session won't lose their session as well like what a `isset($_SESSION['id'])` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$session = isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : null;
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked like a charm. I didn't want to remove the error messages so I know what is wrong with the site. You don't know how much trouble you saved me.